# How to ignore a property when doing Insert or Update but not in Get in SqlKata

Tags: c#, sqlkata

In MySql database, I have columns "created" and "updated" which are marked with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP respectively.
I never want to manually update these fields, but I do want to read them.
SqlKata has Ignore property, but that completely ignores it (surprise!). Is there something like IgnoreOnInsert or similar workaround?

Now I go around this by having a sub-object that does not have these 2 properties, but this is not nice.

Comment: The `Ignore` attribute does not ignore them while reading.

Comment: @amd Thank you very much. I completely misunderstood the [Ignore] attribute. Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Ignore` attribute only affect Insert/Update operations, select statements are not affected.

Comment: is there an Ignore only for updates? We create ids code-wise and insert the id, but would like to ignore the id by an update.